# Template inheritance in odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I want to create a new theme for odoo. I have done it by create a new module and install it. I see in this document [here](https://doc.odoo.com/trunk/web/qweb/) which said that odoo support template inheritance by using t-extend keyword. However I can't make it.
This is my customized template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <template id="website.homepage" name="Homepage" page="True">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>FOO<h1>
            <div class="main">
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template id="website.contact" name="Homepage" page="True">
        <t t-extend="website.homepage">
            <t t-jquery="div.main" t-operation="inner">
                <h1>FOO 2</h1>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>

</data>
</openerp>
```

Template website.contact should have showed FOO and FOO 2 but it only showed FOO 2.
Please help me explain it. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You use a syntax for *client side* templates, but those are *server side* templates. You use inheritance with server side templates this:

```
<template id="contact" inherit_id="website.homepage">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='main']" position="inside">
        <h1>FOO 2</h1>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

You can read more [in the official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html#inheritance).

Comment: Do as you said, it modifies the page website.homepage, not create a new page (website.contact). Is there anyway to create a new page which inherit from a page and doesn't change the original one?

Comment: And seems that it's client side, not server side template, what I did is follow this instruction: http://odoo-80.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/themes.html

Comment: @Minh-Hung Nguyen Those are server side templates (i.e. they are evaluated on the server side) - you link to a correct guide, but the guide doesn't mention `t-extend` anywhere precisely because it's a guide for server side templates, and `t-extend` is a client side (JavaScript) templates feature.

Comment: I think part of your confusion may come from the fact that inheritance in Odoo doesn't typically *create* a new object. It *modifies* an existing object in place. To create a new template based on another templates features you may want to use `t-call` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please tell me in which case can we use t-extend?

Comment: For example when creating widgets for Odoo (the ERP system itself, not an Odoo-powered website).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create new theme.? and are you using odoo 8.0.? I am asking this because the link you posted is for OpenERP 7.0 
So for Odoo 8.0 new documentation is available see [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0) and for QWEB you can find it here [QWEB](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html).

Now Main thing if you are trying to create new theme for CMS or Website module then you must go through these [steps](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/themes.html).

Comment: Thank you for your links, I am using odoo 8 but seems that I watched wrong docs. I tried replace t-extend by t-extends but still unsuccess.

Answer (score 1):

Using Xpath here you can Inherit and make changes on parent tempaltes, examples follows.

```
    <template id="homepage_extend" inherit_id="website.homepage">
      <xpath expr="//div[@class='main']" position='inside'>
        <h1>FOO 2</h1>
      </xpath>
    </template>
```

or try

```
  <template id="homepage_extend" inherit_id="website.homepage">
      <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" position='replace'>
        <div class="header">
          <h1>FOO<h1>
          <div class="main">
            <h1>FOO 2</h1>
          </div>
       </div>
      </xpath>
    </template>
```

You can also try these by overriding that template like:

```
 <template id="website.homepage">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>FOO<h1>
        <div class="main">
          <h1>FOO 2<h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

while overriding don't forget to gave the exact id followed by module name.
Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

In parent template, add `<t t-raw="0"/>` or `<t t-raw="name"/>`, template: ...code html...

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/qweb.html

Answer (score -1):

**Hello Minh-Hung Nguyen,**

Try this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <template id="website.homepage" name="Homepage" page="True">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>FOO<h1>
            <div class="main">
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template id="website.contact" name="Homepage" page="True">
        <t t-extend="website.homepage">
            <!-- Use 'append' to add the h1 tag inside main div -->
            <t t-jquery="main" t-operation="append">
                <h1>FOO 2</h1>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>

</data>
</openerp>
```

**I hope my answer is helpfull for you.**